# Whats the difference between using query runner and DataSource for a transaction?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, transactions, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I want to make a atomic transaction.I'm using typeorm in my repository. And my transaction contains two different entity. What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion better way is queryRunner.

Im using this template to do all operation in one transaction. I have Postgresql and queryRunner create one connection from pool. It is more managment by developer if your pool is small number.

```
const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
await queryRunner.connect();
await queryRunner.startTransaction();
try {
  await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
  return response;
}
except(err) {
   await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
  throw new InternalServerErrorException(err);
}
finally {
  await queryRunner.release();
}
```